# Address of a public function from a C++ class

Tags: c++, c

My application needs parts of a C++ code to be called from a C program.
The problem arises when i have to obtain  the address of a public function.
I do not know how to get the address of a public function from a class.
I specifically need the address so that i can pass the address as a function pointer.
Any other solutions to circumvent the solution are also welcome.
I have tried static casting but it has not worked.

```
static_cast<izot_events*>(thisizot_events)->myIzotWink()
```

This calls the function but i am interested in the address.
I have tried using

```
static_cast<izot_events*>(thisizot_events)->myIzotWink
```

But this returns an error.
Here is also some code for reference.

```
void* C_Create() { return new izot_events(); }
thisizot_events = C_Create();
static_cast<izot_events*>(thisizot_events)->myIzotWink // This does not work i.e I cant get the value.
static_cast<izot_events*>(thisizot_events)->myIzotWink() // While this gets called
```

Comment: What is the type of `thisizot_events`? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: (void*) thisizot_events .Erstwhile it points to the class which contains the function but i have typecasted it to void*

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Comment: You need to make the function `static`, then you can do `&MyClass::my_function`.  You should not do any casting; instead make your static function have the right declaration to match the function pointer's type. (You didn't actually show us that type so we can't be more specific).

Comment: void myIzotWink(void){}

Answer (score 0):

Make the function static, then you can do &MyClass::my_function. You should not do any casting; instead make your static function have the right declaration to match the function pointer's type.